# Como fazer a contagem de números consecutivos iguais em uma lista em Python?

Tags: python, lista

Por exemplo, na lista: [30, 30, 30, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30]
O número 40 se repete 5 vezes consecutivas, e o número 30, se repete 6 vezes. Ele se repete três vezes no início mas o que quero contar é o maior número de repetições de um número específico.

```
n = int(input())
numeros = str(input()).split()
maximo = 0
for numero in numeros:
    contador_numero = 0
    for c in range(0, n):
        if numeros[c] == numero:
            contador_numero += 1
            if contador_numero> maximo:
                maximo = contador_numero
        else:
            contador_numero = 0

print(maximo)
```

Answer (score 1):

Antes de responder tenho que fazer algumas observações:

> **OBS1:**
>
> De todo o seu código a linha que mais me chamou atenção é:
>
> `numeros = str(input()).split()`
>
> Isso `str(input())` não se faz, se for ver a [documentação para a
> função nativa `input()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#input) verá que o resultado de `input()` já é uma
> string e assim não precisando fazer a conversão sendo o suficiente:
>
> `numeros = input().split()`

> **OBS2:**
>
> Se analisarmos sua pergunta é fácil chegar a conclusão de que o
> objetivo é trabalhar com listas numéricas e não listas de string.
> Isso `[30, 30, 30, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30]` do
> ponto de vista computacional é diferente disso `["30", "30", "30", "40", "40", "40", "40", "40", "30", "30", "30", "30", "30", "30"]`
> pois como vai fazer um algoritmo de contagem de repetição números.
> Veja:
>
> ```
> entrada = input("digite uma lista de números:\n").split() # Recebe uma string de caracteres numéricos separados por espaço
>                                                           #e a quebra em uma lista de strings de caracteres.  
>
> print("Lista inserida: ", entrada)                        #Apenas imprime a lista  entrada se a tratar.
>
> print("Lista tratada: ", [int(e) for e in entrada])       #Tranforma os caracteres da entrada em numeros inteiros.
>
> #digite uma lista de números: 
> #30 30 30 40 40 40 40 40 30 30 30 30 30 30
> #Lista inserida:  ['30', '30', '30', '40', '40', '40', '40', '40', '30', '30', '30', '30', '30', '30']
> #Lista tratada:  [30, 30, 30, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30]
> ```
>
> <sup>Teste o exemplo no [IDEOne](https://ideone.com/XQSeCU)</sup>
> Mas porque isso? Porque existem vantagens computacionais em trabalhar
> como o tipo correto e a comparação entre tipos numéricos é menos custosa em relação
> a comparação entre strings.

> **OBS3:**
>
> A resposta a seguir presume uma situação hipotética onde as entradas
> inseridas pelo usuários são perfeitas não precisando serem tratadas, o
> ideal é sempre verificar as entradas inseridas pelo usuário pois podem
> variar de simples erros de digitação a código malicioso, uma sugestão
> seria uma função que inquerisse o usuário a corrigir entradas erradas:
>
> ```
> def tratar_entrada(e):
>   while not e.isdecimal():
>       e = input(f"A string {e} é invalida digite um número inteiro:\n")
>   return e
>
> entrada = input("digite uma lista de números:\n").split()
> print("Lista tratada: ", [tratar_entrada(e) for e in entrada])
> ```
>
> <sup>Teste o exemplo no [IDEOne.com](https://ideone.com/bcpyBU)</sup>

Para contar o maior número de repetições consecutivas de um número específico uma opção é mater um dicionário contendo os dados de contagens dos números.
A chave desse dicionário será um número obtido na lista de números e os valor é uma lista cujo os elementos são contagens de repetições consecutivas da chave dentro da lista números por exemplo:

Se a lista `numeros` for...

```
numeros = [30, 30, 30, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 30, 30, 30, 20, 20, 30, 30, 50, 20]
```

...então o dicionário `resultados` será:

| Chave | Valor |
| --- | --- |
| 30 | `[3, 3, 2]` |
| 40 | `[5]` |
| 20 | `[2, 1]` |
| 50 | `[1]` |

Ou seja no par chave/valor `30: [3, 3, 2]` significa que primeiro foram contadas três repetições consecutivas do número `30`, depois foram contadas mais três repetições consecutivas do número `30` e finalmente foram contadas duas repetições consecutivas do número `30`.

Para tal o algoritmo é simples, basta manter duas variáveis `i`,`f`, índices inteiros indicando o inicio e o fim de um vetor de repetição , que manterão o inicio e fim de um vetor de repetições:

```
[30, 30, 30, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 30, 30, 30, 20, 20, 30, 30, 50, 20]
  ↑           ↑ 
 i=0         f=3  ➡ f - i = 3 repetições de 30
[30, 30, 30, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 30, 30, 30, 20, 20, 30, 30, 50, 20]
              ↑                  ↑ 
             i=3                f=8  ➡ f - i = 5 repetições de 40
[30, 30, 30, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 30, 30, 30, 20, 20, 30, 30, 50, 20]
                                  ↑           ↑ 
                                 i=8         f=11  ➡ f - i = 3 repetições de 30
[30, 30, 30, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 30, 30, 30, 20, 20, 30, 30, 50, 20]
                                              ↑       ↑ 
                                             i=11    f=13  ➡ f - i = 2 repetições de 20
[30, 30, 30, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 30, 30, 30, 20, 20, 30, 30, 50, 20]
                                                      ↑       ↑ 
                                                     i=13    f=15  ➡ f - i = 2 repetições de 30
[30, 30, 30, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 30, 30, 30, 20, 20, 30, 30, 50, 20]
                                                              ↑   ↑ 
                                                            i=13 f=15  ➡ f - i = 1 repetições de 50
[30, 30, 30, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 30, 30, 30, 20, 20, 30, 30, 50, 20]
                                                                  ↑    ↑ 
                                                                 i=13 f=len(numeros)  ➡ f - i = 1 repetições de 20
```

Depois de obter e tabular a as contagens de cada elemento em um dicionário  fica fácil fazer extrair dados que precisar. No exemplo abaixo usei as funções nativas [`min()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#max) e [`max()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#max) para respectivamente extrair o menor e o maior número de repetições:

```python
#Entrada tratada
numeros = [30, 30, 30, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 30, 30, 30, 20, 20, 30, 30, 50, 20]

num = numeros[0]                 #Declara um marcador para o número que está sendo contado
i,f = 0,0                        #Declara os índices para o vetor de repetições
resultados = {}                  #Declara o dicionário onde serão mantidos os resultados 

#Enquanto o índice f for menor ou igual ao comprimento de números...
while f <= len(numeros):
  ##...se f igual ao comprimento de números ou numeros[f] não for um número repetido....
  if f == len(numeros) or numeros[f] != num:
    ##...se em resultado já existir uma chave num... 
    if num in resultados:                     
      resultados[num].append(f-i)                     ###...adicione o resultado de f-i a lista resultados[num].
    else:
      resultados[num] = [f-i]                         ###...caso contrário crie uma chave resultados[num] cujo o valor seja uma lista povoada pelo resultado f-i.
    i=f                                               ##... faça i iguala f.
    ##...se f não extrapolar o tamanho de numeros....
    if f < len(numeros):
      num = numeros[f]                                ###...num recebe numeros[f].
  f+=1                                                #...incremente f.

for k,v in resultados.items():
  print(f'O elemento {k}:')
  print(f'\t- menor número de repetições: {min(v)}')
  print(f'\t- maior número de repetições: {max(v)}')

#O elemento 30:
#    - menor número de repetições: 2
#    - maior número de repetições: 3
#O elemento 40:
#    - menor número de repetições: 5
#    - maior número de repetições: 5
#O elemento 20:
#    - menor número de repetições: 1
#    - maior número de repetições: 2
#O elemento 50:
#    - menor número de repetições: 1
#    - maior número de repetições: 1
```

<sup>Teste o exemplo no [IDEOne.com](https://ideone.com/a8TdTT)</sup>

Caso seja estritamente necessário apenas obter o maior número de repetições basta no dicionário de resultados ao invés de mater uma lista contendo os números de repetições consecutivas mantenha um inteiro contendo a maior contagem encontrada

```python
numeros = [30, 30, 30, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 30, 30, 30, 20, 20, 30, 30, 50, 20]
num = numeros[0]
i,f = 0,0
resultados = {}

while f <= len(numeros):
  if f == len(numeros) or numeros[f] != num:
    if num in resultados:
      if f-i > resultados[num]:
        resultados[num].append(f-i)
    else:
      resultados[num] = f-i
    i=f  
    if f < len(numeros):
      num = numeros[f]
  f+=1

for k,v in resultados.items():
  print(f'O maior número de repetições do elemento {k} é {v} ')
#O maior número de repetições do elemento 30 é 3 
#O maior número de repetições do elemento 40 é 5 
#O maior número de repetições do elemento 20 é 2 
#O maior número de repetições do elemento 50 é 1
```

<sup>Teste o exemplo no [IDEOne.com](https://ideone.com/PWUKwY)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Complementando as outras respostas, daria para fazer usando [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```py
from itertools import groupby

numeros = [30, 30, 30, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30]
repeticoes = {}
for n, grupo in groupby(numeros):
    tamanho = len(list(grupo))
    if n not in repeticoes or tamanho > repeticoes[n]:
        repeticoes[n] = tamanho

for n, tamanho in repeticoes.items():
    print(f'O número {n} se repete {tamanho} vezes')
```

`groupby` retorna grupos de valores consecutivos (justamente o que você precisa). Sendo assim, para cada grupo, basta verificar se o número já esteve em algum grupo anterior. Se não esteve, ou se já esteve mas o tamanho do grupo atual é maior que o do anterior, eu adiciono no dicionário que guarda os resultados.

Ao final teremos um dicionário contendo os números e a quantidade de repetições. No caso do código acima, a saída será:

```
O número 30 se repete 6 vezes
O número 40 se repete 5 vezes
```

Answer (score 0):

Imagino que o resultado necessitaria ser no mínimo um dicionário chave-valor, onde a chave seria algum identificador da sequência e o valor conteria a quantidade de repetições.

Pensei em uma função na qual, dado a lista de entrada que você descreveu, a saída seria nesse formato:

```py
{
    "0":([30, 30, 30], 3),
    "1":([40, 40, 40, 40, 40], 5),
    "2":([30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30], 6)
}
```

E a função cheguei nessa solução:

```py
def countConsecutiveNumbers(lstNumbers:list):
    dictConsecutiveNumbers = dict()
    currentNumber = lstNumbers[0]
    currentSeq = list()
    id = 0
    countLoop = 1
    for n in lstNumbers:
        if n != currentNumber:
            dictConsecutiveNumbers[id] = (currentSeq, len(currentSeq))
            id += 1
            currentNumber = n
            currentSeq = [n]
        elif len(lstNumbers)==countLoop:
            currentSeq.append(n)
            dictConsecutiveNumbers[id] = (currentSeq, len(currentSeq))
        elif n == currentNumber:
            currentSeq.append(n)
        countLoop += 1
    return dictConsecutiveNumbers
```